# Java word clock

Tags: java

I am trying to make a word clock but I am running into so problems early on. The problem is simple but I cant seem to get it to work. What I am  doing is reading the date into a variable, I am then trying to change the time string into an array, next I am trying to take the first element of the array and compare it with the number two. If it is 2 it should print out 'two' and if not 'it is not two'

I have the string in the array but my loop doesnt seem to be working. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Time3{
    public static void main (String args[]){

        Date time = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        String time_to_string = df.format(time);

        char[] timeArray = time_to_string.toCharArray();

        //System.out.println("The time is " + time_to_string);

        //System.out.print("String element 0 is: ");
        //System.out.println(timeArray[0]);

        if (timeArray[0] == 2){
            System.out.println("Two");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("It is not two");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: _I have the string in the array but my loop doesnt seem to be working._ What loop?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change your code to this:

```
    if (timeArray[0] == '2'){
        System.out.println("Two");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("It is not two");
    }
```

**EDIT** - you also have an array which is holding the numbers as words like:

```
String[] numbersAsWords = new String[]{"Zero","One","Two","Three","Four"....};
numbersAsWords[timeArray[0]] -->> will return what you need
```

Comment: Just to provide an explanation: Hayes121 had an array of `char`, and he was trying to compare one of the `char` in it to an `int`. He should have used the `char` `'2'` instead to have matching types.

Comment: Thanks very much, did you add the '' because it is a character array?